# control order of js file loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a small problem here which I really am quite stuck in right now

My problem:

when a connection to google maps loads slowly, the rest of my JS files wati for the connection to be finished

What I want to do

Load all my JS files before a connection to google maps is made

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Rearrange the order in which the script tags appear

Comment: Be aware that JS files on your webpage might possibly only load quickly because your computer is close to your webserver. Unless you have fast webservers distributed across the planet that are directly plugged into the Internet Backbone like Google do, then most people will find that the Google JS files load faster than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your scripts early in the head. And you can load scripts synchronously (only if you *need* to load them in right order) like this (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    url: js_base+script.split('.').join('/')+'.js', //mine specific. you can use simple '/js/a.js' url
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'script',
    async: false,
    global:false,
});
```